# Copy and paste twice

Tags: copy-paste, clipboard

Is there a way, to copy and paste twice? For example, is there a way, for me to copy one url, store it, and then copy another url, and then for the urls to be pasted respectively?

I read somewhere, that this is possible, but have not ben able to figure it out.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you need a [clipboard manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_manager). There are many good ones around; may I suggest reading up on Wikipedia an article to see what they do; then it'll be easy from there to find one that suits your needs best.

Answer (score 3):

Copy one, paste it into notepad/gedit/kwrite/textedit/vi/emacs. Copy two, paste it into same [insert text editor of choice]. Copy both, paste both. :)

Comment: Aside from being painfully inconvenient, this doesn't quite sound like what Shane is looking for. Edit: Sorry, I guess the humor didn't come across on this one.

Comment: Guys, I know clipboards are serious business but everyone could use a good chuckle. Even if it's forced. Go ahead, read my answer and give it a try. Please???